# I would like to combined 2 formulas into one in a cell. (EXCEL)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

The formula below is what I came up with:

```
=INDEX('111'!A2:A10,SMALL(IF('111'!D2:D10>EOMONTH(TODAY(),2),IF('111'!D2:D10<>"",MATCH('111'!A2:A10,'111'!A2:A10,0))),ROW(A2:A10)-ROW(A1)),ROW(A1))

=INDEX('181'!A2:A10,SMALL(IF('181'!D2:D10>EOMONTH(TODAY(),2),IF('181'!D2:D10<>"",MATCH('181'!A2:A10,'181'!A2:A10,0))),ROW(A2:A10)-ROW(A1)),ROW(A1))
```

Its exactly the same thing, just that the sheets they are referencing on is different.

Is there a way to combine them so that I can get information from both worksheets onto one row instead of 2 rows?

Or should I use VBA?

Comment: it looks like you are missing a few **$**'s in those formulas.

Comment: I don't think you can reliably concatenate results from two array formulas in a single cell. you probably should have mentioned that fact. switch your index/small/match to index/aggregate and you won't require cse.

Comment: @Jeeped I so very rarely use array formulas I never recognise them unless they are written with the braces around them :D

Comment: @Jeeped I realised it was intended at the OP, but I was embarrassed anyway for not having noticed :D

Comment: Does $ makes a difference? Sorry asking a noob question haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this index/aggregate that produces cyclic calculation without having to be entered with cse,

```
=INDEX('111'!A$2:A$10, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$9)/(('111'!D$2:D$10>EOMONTH(TODAY(), 2))*('111'!D$2:D$10<>"")), ROW(1:1)))&
 ":"&
 INDEX('181'!A$2:A$10, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$9)/(('181'!D$2:D$10>EOMONTH(TODAY(), 2))*('181'!D$2:D$10<>"")), ROW(1:1)))
```

Comment: The results is the first answer of both sheets like this 

(Answer 1:Answer 2)
(Answer 1:Answer 2)
(Answer 1:Answer 2)
(Answer 1:Answer 2)


It becomes repetitive.

Comment: Oh i realise i didnt have to press CSE. Apologies. What i'm looking for isnt them side by side but rather, one name = one cell. sorry for not being informative about.

Comment: is there a way to fix this? 

=INDEX(('181'!A$2:A$10)*('111'!A$2:A$10), AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$9)/((('181'!D$2:D$10)*('111'!D$2:D$10)>EOMONTH(TODAY(), 2))*(('181'!D$2:D$10)*('111'!D$2:D$10)<>"")), ROW(1:1)))

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand you correctly, but the INDIRECT functionncould solve your issue. It turns a formula entered as a string into a real formula.

So, if you have your sheet names in two cells one below the other, lets say A1:A2, just concatenate parts of your formula together, replacing the 111 and 181 parts with

*“ & A1 & “*

Hope this helps.

Comment: Apologies that i didn't make it clearer. I'm looking for a formula where i can pick out names from sheet 181 and 111 when a certain criteria is met. However, i can only put the names onto one row and the names will be expandable. Thus i can't keep the formula fixated to one cell only, that's why i'm using array. Would there be a formula that might be able to process the above mentioned into one row or must i use VBA?